# Voyager Bread Update Function URL

Tags: laravel, voyager

I am trying to manually submit a form after the user clicks on the submit button.

How do i get the URL of the update function being handled by voyager BREAD?

Answer (score 0):

Override the controller of that bread. see [using custom controller](https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/customization/overriding-files#using-custom-controllers-1)

Create a new controller `ControllerName` and extend `VoyagerBaseController` to override `update` method

```
Class ControllerName extends \TCG\Voyager\Http\Controllers\VoyagerBaseController {
    public function update(Request $request, $id) {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

Edit your bread set controller your controller name like App\Http\Controllers\ControllerName
[image]

Comment: but how do i send manually send a request to call this update function on button click if i were to disable the form submit event